Maximal spectrum of a ring is irreducible iff the ring is an integral domain
Let $A$ be a commutative ring. We note $m$-$\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ its maximal spectrum, i.e. the subset of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ formed by maximal ideals of $A$ (or, that is the same thing, the closed points of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ according to the Zariski topology).
I would like to show that $m$-$\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is irreducible as a topological space, if and only if, $A$ is an integral domain.
I have tried to use that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is irreducible iff the nilradical of $A$ is prime, without result in any of the two implications.
Any help? (Not complete answers please.)

This is not correct. Take $A = k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ for example. Here $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \mathrm{SpecMax}(A)$ has just one point and is therefore irreducible.
From the definitions it is easy to deduce that $\mathrm{SpecMax}(A)$ is irreducible iff the Jacobson radical $\mathrm{Jac}(A)$ is a prime ideal of $A$. The proof works exactly as for $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. In other words:
$\mathrm{SpecMax}(A)$ is irreducible $\iff$ the quotient $A/\mathrm{Jac}(A)$ is an integral domain
In general, notice that the closed embedding $\mathrm{SpecMax}(A/\mathrm{Jac}(A)) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{SpecMax}(A)$ is a homeomorphism. So every topological property of $\mathrm{SpecMax}(A)$ will actually be a property of $A / \mathrm{Jac}(A)$, not of $A$.

Thanks so much!
